# i want to add thickness to my model of a helmet, but i only want it to change the inside

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a model of a helmet which I intend to 3d print, however it is too thin. how to I add a thickness to the inside of the helmet without changing the look of the outside?

this is the inside of the helmet
[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a Solidify Modifier? It will only create thickness on the inside.